# No module named '*.urls'

Tags: python, django, django-urls

So I'm creating a new Django app, which I've done a couple of times. However, right now it looks like it's not possible to add the include from django.urls for some reason?

I keep getting the "No module named companies.urls" whilst it's 100% there...

Here is the setup:

**urls.py** - includes "companies.urls", redirecting to companies/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('companies.urls'), name='Companies'),
]
```

**companies/urls.py** - the urls.py where it refers to

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import *

app_name = 'Companies'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes, name='Router'),
    path('companies/', views.getCompanies, name='getCompanies'),
]
```

**settings.py** - showing that the app "companies" is added to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'companies',
]
```

Please help me out, I'm really at a loss here. I basically started copying from an older Django project where it does work. But I'm running Django 4.0.4 and the documentation sides with my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the solution. I'm used to working with IntelliJ but since it doesn't have good JS support (for free) I switched to VSCode. I forgot to specify the file extension of companies/urls. Its name was "urls" instead of "urls.py".